# How Fuzzy Grouping in SSIS chooses its base record

Tags: ssis, grouping, fuzzy-search

I am using Fuzzy Grouping for finding fuzzy matches of Name.The base record against which the remaining records are matched depends on the amount of data.

I wanted to know the way this components finds out the base record (parent record against which all fuzzy matching records are calculated). Is it based on the Name string which is longer in length or based on the first input record that is encountered?

Anybody has any idea how this Fuzzy component works?

I know that this might be a patented algorithm, but just a little insight?